# How can I transfer long list of numeric R output into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, output

I am working in the package SubCultCon, which yields long lists of numeric data as output, that I want to get into dataframes for further analysis. For example, the below up to 400+.

```
  [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
 [55] 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
```

How can I move this (and other ouptut similarly generated by SubCultCon) into a dataframe? I have used

```
test_subset <- data.frame(
  group = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
)
```

But had to manually add the ","

I looked at ways to auto-add commas but solutions appear for data generated in a column or prettyNum which don't fit this case.

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: Use `dput` to get the values in structure.  Or perhaps you need just `data.frame(group = youroutputobject)`

Comment: It looks like you're not assigning the result of whatever function produces the output. Assign it with `<-` and give it a name, `my_output <- your_SubCultCon_function(...)`. You can then put the output directly into a data frame, `test_subset <- data.frame(group = my_output)`.

Comment: If you need more help, please show the line of code that produces your numeric output.

Comment: your output look like a numeric vector? so `data.frame(group = youroutput)` should work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Preferred, assign the expression to a variable so that you can reuse it:

   ```r
   obj <- somefunc(...)
   #   [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
   #  [55] 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
   ```
2. If something is `print`ing something to the console (bad practice) and it cannot be captured as above, then highlight and copy the text desired and run this:

   ```r
   obj <- strsplit(trimws(paste(gsub("\\[[0-9]+\\]", "", readLines("clipboard")), collapse = " ")), "\\s+")[[1]]
   # Warning in readLines("clipboard") :
   #   incomplete final line found on 'clipboard'
   obj
   #   [1] "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2"
   #  [32] "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1"
   #  [63] "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
   #  [94] "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2"
   ```

   If you need it to be integers or floating-point numbers, then follow-up with one of the following (or wrap in the original call):

   ```r
   obj <- as.integer(obj)
   # or
   obj <- as.numeric(obj)
   ```

After all of that, you now have `obj` which can be assigned to a `data.frame` (or anything else) as desired.